# Reading user-specific environment variables in Chef

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I'm new to Chef and Ruby and trying to understand how I can read an environment variable from a specific Linux/Windows user and use it to place a file.

What I want to do is update our Oracle `tnsnames.ora` files for client and DB installations.

These files may be in a directory like `C:\oracle` or `C:\Program Files\oracle` in Windows or `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2/network/admin` or `/u01/app/oracle/producdt/10.2/network/admin` in Linux.

I can't be 100% sure I will know the exact location without reading an environment variable into the recipe and using it.

I was reading about `#{ENV['HOME']}` but I can't quite figure out if that is the type of syntax I would like to use or not.

Comment: Use `ENV['HOME']`, not `#{ENV['HOME']}`. The second only applies if you're embedding it in a string. Your code will have to be running as that user to read their environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As I'm thinking about this I was thinking about the `recipes/default.rb` and the `template` block of code. 

`template "#{ENV['ORACLE_HOME']}/network/admin/tnsnames.ora" do
 source "tnsnames.ora.erb"
 owner "oracle"
        group "dba"
 mode "0644"
end`

This doesn't seem right still though...

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby has a native method for doing this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-home). I suspect

```
template "#{Dir.home("oracle")}/network/admin/tnsnames.ora" do
    source "tnsnames.ora.erb"
    [...]
end
```

Will do approximately what you want. This only works if there's no difference between operating systems besides the location of the home directory, of course.